# Remove product description from product archive page

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic

The shop page of WooCommerce is based on the `archive-product.php` file. In this file, a loop is called:

```
    <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_subcategories(); ?>

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php
                    /**
                     * woocommerce_shop_loop hook.
                     *
                     * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 10
                     */
                    do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop' );
                ?>

                <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

In this loop, product data is generated:

```
public function generate_product_data( $product = null ) {
        if ( ! is_object( $product ) ) {
            global $product;
        }

        if ( ! is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
            return;
        }

        $shop_name       = get_bloginfo( 'name' );
        $shop_url        = home_url();
        $currency        = get_woocommerce_currency();
        $markup          = array();
        $markup['@type'] = 'Product';
        $markup['@id']   = get_permalink( $product->get_id() );
        $markup['url']   = $markup['@id'];
        $markup['name']  = $product->get_name();

        if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_structured_data_product_limit', is_product_taxonomy() || is_shop() ) ) {
            $this->set_data( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_structured_data_product_limited', $markup, $product ) );
            return;
        }

        if ( '' !== $product->get_price() ) {
            $markup_offer = array(
                '@type'         => 'Offer',
                'priceCurrency' => $currency,
                'availability'  => 'https://schema.org/' . $stock = ( $product->is_in_stock() ? 'InStock' : 'OutOfStock' ),
                'sku'           => $product->get_sku(),
                'image'         => wp_get_attachment_url( $product->get_image_id() ),
                'description'   => $product->get_description(),
                'seller'        => array(
                    '@type' => 'Organization',
                    'name'  => $shop_name,
                    'url'   => $shop_url,
                ),
            );
...
```

There is a line in the `generate_product_data function` calling for the product description.

I'd like to adapt my template or add a function in my `functions.php` file so the description is no longer added to my product archive page. However, it should be added to my single product page. Product archive page & single product page use the same `woocommerce_shop_loop` however.

How should I adapt the template or add code to my functions file to remove this product description? I have long descriptions for my products & don't want these to be added to the product archive pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was for the following for **the7 template**:
[image: Solution]

If anybody knows how to implement this in the `functions.php` file so I don't have to update this when my theme updates, shoot!

Answer (score 0):

For this specific theme you can add

```
remove_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_desc','dt_woocommerce_template_loop_product_short_desc', 15);
```

in functions.php of the child theme to remove the action, `dt_woocommerce_template_loop_product_short_desc` this function is added to `woocommerce_shop_loop_item_desc`, by using remove_action it'll be removed.

Update: It seems like you are removing action before init, child theme's function is executed before parent theme, kindly try

```
function remove_parent_action() {                                            
    remove_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_desc','dt_woocommerce_template_loop_product_short_desc', 15);
}
add_filter('init', 'remove_parent_action');
```

Comment: Hi Akshat, I tried to add this function to my functions.php file but it did not work unfortunately. In the meantime, I have gained some more insight about the hooks, which I have posted here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/333556/remove-action-on-product-archive-page?noredirect=1#comment491095_333556

Comment: Ideally this should have worked, you'll have to debug if there's anything missed, or you can try adding higher priority to remove action.

Comment: OK Akshat, I'll give it another try later on. Shouldn't my priority be exactly the same as the which was used when adding the action?

Comment: no, the priority should be either equal or greater than the add_action priority.

Answer (score 0):

2021 working solution. In your child theme, add this to functions.php

```
/**
 * Products Shop Archive Short Description
 *
 * @param  string $string
 * @return string
 */

function woo_archive_desc( $string ) {
    global $post;

// Don't display the description on search results page.  

if ( is_search() ) {
    return;
}

// Only run function if on Woo Shop Page

if ( is_post_type_archive( 'product' ) ) {

    $shop_page = get_post( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) && in_array( absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ), array( 0, 1 ), true ) );
    if ( $shop_page ) {
        $des = $post->post_excerpt;

// do something like empty above var, then echo
     
        echo '<div class="woocommerce-product-details__short-description"><p>' . $des . '</p></div>';

    }
}
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woo_archive_desc', 4, 1 );
```

Lastly move...

`plugins/woocommerce/single-product/short-description.php` to `themes/{yourthemehere}/woocommerce/single-product/short-description.php`

Change this code block adding `! is_product()` to condition.

```
global $post;

$short_description = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt );

if ( ! $short_description || ! is_product() ) {
    return;
}
```