# Remove action on product archive page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, hooks, actions

I have a **product description** which is hooked into my **product archive page** in the following way by my **theme (The7)**:

```
/**
 * display short desc hook.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_rating - 5
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_price - 10
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_desc' );
```

In my template setting, I have a way of hiding this product description but this just hides the div with the description by using **CSS** `display: none;`

This is not good, as in the background, the description is still loaded & this has a negative effect on the **performance** of the page.

Therefore, I want to **remove the action**. I now did it by commenting it in the template file, but everytime I update the theme I'm screwed.

I tried to remove the action by adding the following code in my `functions.php` file (source: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action) but this did not work:

```
/* Remove product description on product archive page */
remove_action( 'woocommerce_template_loop_rating','woocommerce_shop_loop_item_desc', 5);
remove_action( 'woocommerce_template_loop_price','woocommerce_shop_loop_item_desc', 10);
```

Anybody has an idea on how to correctly remove the action?

Comment: This seems the same as the topic [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/284164/remove-product-description-from-product-archive-page) not sure why it wouldn't work for you. It's the only right method.

Comment: Hi Karun, unfortunately, this does not work. The description is still loaded after adding the code to my functions.php file.

Comment: I just realized in your code, you've set `woocommerce_shop_loop_item_desc` as a hook and to remove you used `woocommerce_shop_loop_item_desc` as function. You probably have some other function hooked into the `woocommerce_shop_loop_item_desc`.

Comment: Can I give you some more information? The comment is not really helping me right now. Anyway, thank you for your time!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove product description from product archive page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/284164/remove-product-description-from-product-archive-page)

Answer (score 2):

First thing, regarding your comment "everytime I update the theme I'm screwed" - you should always use a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) when doing any customisations .

Second, your `remove_action` call is wrong. As per the documentation you've linked to already, it sates that the first argument is `$tag` and the second is `$function_to_remove`. Right now, your arguments are reversed.

So the correct call would be

```
/* Remove product description on product archive page */
remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_desc', 'woocommerce_template_loop_rating', 5);
remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_desc', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10);
```

Update:

if the above solution doesn't work, it might be because the hook triggers after theme setup. In this case you can try the following :

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_remove_parent_theme_stuff', 0 );

function my_remove_parent_theme_stuff() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_desc', 'woocommerce_template_loop_rating', 5);
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_desc', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10);

}
```

Comment: Hi, will try this tonight. Thanks for you answer . Indeed, I will remove the action in my functions.php file in the child theme so a theme update doesn’t overwrite this. I tried to do this before but as my call was incorrect, this did not work. How do you know what is the tag & what is the function in this case? I cannot seperate these very well.

Comment: You can see in the comments above the `do_action` call what functions are hooked into it. Those hooks mean that when WordPress executes the `woocommerce_shop_loop_item_desc` action (function) it also calls the functions attached, in the order specified by the priority tag (5,10 etc - higher numbers are executed later). Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Hi Mihai, it answers my question, but I just tried this code on my website, but unfortunately it did not solve the issue :(.

Comment: I've updated the answer in case the issue is with the timing of when the hooks get triggered. Try that and see if it works.

Comment: @BarrieO did the updated solution work ? If so, consider marking the question as answered.

Comment: sorry I was really busy with some other projects. Tried the solution just now, but unfortunately, it did not work.